# Avoid models replication between app and DB

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pydantic

- I have an application with a DB.
- I'm using SQLAlchemy as the orm.
- I have drawn "on paper" my diagram with attributes and relationships between classes of my application.

Now I want to code this diagram in classes of my apps with attributes, methods and relationships.
But I also want that these are reflected into the DB.

In every [example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#__tabbed_1_1) I found for that, **people always write two modules**: one for the **DB schema** (for example in SQLALchemy) and one for the **"app schema"** (in pure python or making use of pydantic), replicating names and attributes between the two.

I don't like replicated structures, because not writing the same things just once exposes you to errors and difficulties in maintaining the code.

Is there a way to **avoid models replication**? And, if not, could you help me understand why it is necessary to write two different but nearly coincident schemas for the same logic?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason is arguable mostly historic. FastAPI uses Pydantic models for defining API schemata. SQLAlchemy is a DB abstraction and ORM. The latter is also much older. They serve distinct purposes. Just because you need an ORM for example, does not mean you are interested in writing a web API.

It just so happened that with the CRUD API paradigm gaining popularity, people started narrowing the gap between the two more and more; API and DB schemata began mapping more and more to one another.

You are by far not the only one coming across this problem of seemingly repeating class definitions almost verbatim because one is a DB model and the other is the API model.

Luckily, the [same guy](https://github.com/tiangolo) who developed FastAPI also started a new project that intends to close this gap and remove the need to do this duplicate definition. It is called [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) and I suggest you check it out.

This is just an opinion: I think it is a great step in the right direction and has lots of potential, but it is still in its early stages, probably not entirely stable, and far from exhaustive in terms of its features. It also currently suffers from the fact that Sebastián seems to have trouble keeping up with the maintenance of the project, likely due to time constraints. But I am still keeping my eye on it. (Got a few PRs there myself in hopes of being merged.)

Comment: Yes SQLModel is really promising but I experienced what you are mentioning: it is still early especially on the docs